# Painting Pre-primed baseboard

Tags: painting

We are putting down new floors and baseboards and the supplier delivered the pre primed baseboard early so that we can paint it before it goes up.  We are going to paint it a semi gloss white.  Can you just paint it or do we have to do any prep work?

Comment: Ensure that your baseboard is stored _inside_ the house so it can acclimate to the temperature and humidity level inside. Wood is a natural product and it will expand and contract with the seasons and current temp/humidity levels. By having it inside, it will adjust itself to the environment and when you cut & miter joints, they'll have the greatest chance of staying tight by having it acclimated.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to clean it in case it got dirty during handling and delivery.  You may also want to touch-up any spots where the primer has rubbed off.

But generally it's not necessary to re-prime pre-primed trim.